# Confusion over the *challenge* tags, on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I recently came across a question tagged with both [**`[challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenge) and [**`[code-challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-challenge). So I decide to investigate these tags.

- [**`[*challeng*]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/~challenge~) 209 questions total

  - [**`[challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenge) 181 questions
  - <s>[**`[code-challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/code-challenge) synonym for [**`[challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenge)</s>
  - <s>[**`[challenging]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenging) 0 questions</s>
  - <s>[**`[android-dev-challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-dev-challenge)</s>
  - [**`[challenge-response]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenge-response) 9 questions
  - [**`[challenges]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenges) 11 questions
  - [**`[python-challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-challenge) 9 questions
  - [**`[ai-challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ai-challenge)
  - [**`[nt-challenge-response]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/nt-challenge-response)

---

The questions tagged [**`[challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenge) fall under these categories:

- **Personal or interpersonal challenge**

  - [Challenges of code review with remote team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731645/challenges-of-code-review-with-remote-team)
  - [What is the most challenging technical problem you’ve solved in your life?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336350/what-is-the-most-challenging-technical-problem-youve-solved-in-your-life)
  - [What should I write in order to become a better developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007007/what-should-i-write-in-order-to-become-a-better-developer)
  - [When have you been put on a new project that was far more challenging than anything you’d worked on before?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075329/when-have-you-been-put-on-a-new-project-that-was-far-more-challenging-than-anythi)

  These only have the [**`[challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenge) tag, because the OP thought it was challenging.

  Personal challenges should probably get the [**`[self-improvement]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/self-improvement) tag.

  The interpersonal challenge questions will probably end up spread across several tags. I'm not sure what these tags will be.

- **Challenge - Response**

  - [What are some efficient ways to generate challenge/response for a backdoor entry scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699149/what-are-some-efficient-ways-to-generate-challenge-response-for-a-backdoor-entry)
  - [Security, crytography: Stupid Challege - Response protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188043/security-crytography-stupid-challege-response-protocol)

  These appear to be mistakenly tagged [**`[challenge]`** + **`[response]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenge+response) instead of [**`[challenge-response]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenge-response)
- **Code Challenge**

  - [Challenge: Getting Linq-to-Entities to generate decent SQL without unnecessary joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924629/challenge-getting-linq-to-entities-to-generate-decent-sql-without-unnecessary-joins)
  - [What are some good programming challenge websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87657/what-are-some-good-programming-challenge-websites)
  - [JavaScript method chaining challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1445747/javascript-method-chaining-challenge)
  - [Most efficient code for the first 10000 prime numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622/most-efficient-code-for-the-first-10000-prime-numbers)
  - [Coding brain teaser to update an array (language agnostic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378925/coding-brain-teaser-to-update-an-array-language-agnostic)

  These should probably be asked somewhere more [appropriate](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

- **Questions which don't really appear to need any [`[*challeng*]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/~challenge~) tag**

  - [USBCELL - Can anyone program this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1659045/usbcell-can-anyone-program-this)
  - [Cool debugging of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542875/cool-debugging-of-an-object)
  - [Finding if a number is a power of 2 without using modulus operator or division operator [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618278/finding-if-a-number-is-a-power-of-2-without-using-modulus-operator-or-division-op)
  - [What’s wrong with this algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666820/whats-wrong-with-this-algorithm)

  The only reason these questions have the [**`[challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenge) tag, is apparently because the OP thought it was challenging. The [**`[challenge]`**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/challenge) tag should just be removed from these.